# SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver never gets hit with regular java exception

Tags: java, spring, exception, soap, spring-ws

Can anyone tell me why I cant catch a regular Java exception with my resolver so I can transform it before the response is sent back?  It never gets hit with a breakpoint.  If its not possible, how can I?

**SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver**

```
public class LisSoapFaultTranslatorExceptionResolver extends SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver {

    @Override
    protected void customizeFault(Object endpoint, Exception ex, SoapFault fault) {

        SoapFaultDetail detail = fault.addFaultDetail();
    }
}
```

**Bean**

```
<sws:annotation-driven />
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping" />
<bean id="exceptionResolver"
            class="com.openclass.adapter.ws.resolvers.LisSoapFaultTranslatorExceptionResolver">
            <property name="defaultFault" value="RECEIVER,Server error">
            </property>
            <property name="exceptionMappings">
                <value>java.lang.Exception=SERVER,FaultMsg</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**Soap Response With Error**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en">java.lang.NullPointerException</faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**Web Service**

```
@PayloadRoot(localPart="readCourseSectionRequest", namespace="http://www.imsglobal.org/services/lis/cmsv1p0/wsdl11/sync/imscms_v1p0")
    @ResponsePayload
    public ReadCourseSectionResponse readCourseSection(@RequestPayload ReadCourseSectionRequest request, MessageContext messageContext) {

            // Throws error since courseService is null
        ReadCourseSectionResponse openClassResponse = courseService.readCourseSection(request);

        return new ReadCourseSectionResponse();
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got it working by adding

```
<property name="order" value="1"></property>
```

to the

```
<bean id="exceptionResolver" class="com.openclass.adapter.ws.resolvers.LisSoapFaultTranslatorExceptionResolver">
```

Comment: ahaaaa, When I worked on a Spring WS project, I remember I had this very same problem. That's why I used annotated exception (@SoapFault). Glad you got it

Answer (score 0):

I think you should, in your exception resolver, override the method getFaultDefinition, something like this (Assuming your resolver is extending AbstractSoapFaultDefinitionExceptionResolver):

```
@Override
protected SoapFaultDefinition getFaultDefinition(Object endpoint, Exception ex) {
    if(ex instanceof LoginException){
        SoapFaultDefinition result = new SoapFaultDefinition();
        result.setFaultCode(QName.valueOf("SERVER"));
        return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

And if you want your fault message (Exception) more customized, you should annotate it like:

```
@SoapFault(faultCode = FaultCode.SERVER)
public class LoginException extends Exception{}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem. I solved it replacing the bean name/id "exceptionResolver" by "soapFaultAnnotationExceptionResolver".

See: [Adding detail in a WS SoapFault : my custom ExceptionResolver is not used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069114/custom-soapfault-exception-resolver-not-being-used/31072552#31072552)