# Adding detail in a WS SoapFault : my custom ExceptionResolver is not used

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-ws

I'm building a web service using Spring Boot (1.2.4.RELEASE) and I'm quite new to this framework.
Especially, **I'm trying to customize the SoapFault content when an exception is thrown** (adding a "detail" tag).

I followed this article to do so : http://www.stevideter.com/2009/02/18/of-exceptionresolvers-and-xmlbeans/

Here is my exception:

```
package foo.bar.exception;

import org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.annotation.FaultCode;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.annotation.SoapFault;

@SoapFault(faultCode = FaultCode.SERVER)
public class ServiceException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1804604596179996724L;

    private String tempFaultDetail;

    public ServiceException(){
        super("ServiceException");
    }

    public ServiceException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public ServiceException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public ServiceException(String message, Throwable cause, String fautDetail) {
        super(message, cause);
        setTempFaultDetail( fautDetail );
    }


    public String getTempFaultDetail() {
        return tempFaultDetail;
    }

    public void setTempFaultDetail(String tempFaultDetail) {
        this.tempFaultDetail = tempFaultDetail;
    }       
}
```

Here is my beans.xml (I tried to do it with Java configuration and annotation, but I'm not sure I'm doing it right, so I backed up to XML bean declaration):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

    <bean id="exceptionResolver"
        class="foo.bar.ws.DetailSoapFaultDefinitionExceptionResolver">
        <property name="defaultFault" value="SERVER" />
        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <value>
                foo.bar.exception.ServiceException=SERVER,FaultMsg
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And the custom class I wrote to override SoapFaultAnnotationExceptionResolver (at first I extended SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver as presented in the article above) :

```
package foo.bar.ws;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapFault;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.SoapFaultAnnotationExceptionResolver;

@Component
public class DetailSoapFaultDefinitionExceptionResolver extends
        SoapFaultAnnotationExceptionResolver {

    public final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( DetailSoapFaultDefinitionExceptionResolver.class );

    public DetailSoapFaultDefinitionExceptionResolver() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void customizeFault(Object endpoint, Exception ex, SoapFault fault) {
        logger.debug("TEST OK !");
    }

}
```

But when I throw a ServiceException in my endpoint, the customizeFault method of the custom class is never hit. And for a good reason, the class used as an exception handler is still SoapFaultAnnotationExceptionResolver and not mine...

Does anyone see an explanation ?

Already looked:

- [SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver never gets hit with regular java exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510743/soapfaultmappingexceptionresolver-never-gets-hit-with-regular-java-exception)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As usual, I solve my problem an hour after posting it online. I should have done it earlier !

The bean name/id I tried to override was not right. After scanning a huge amount of org.springframework.beans debug logs, I found that the right bean name is `soapFaultAnnotationExceptionResolver`.

I also managed to convert the configuration in Java form:

```
package foo.bar.ws;

// Skipping imports...

/**
 * WS configuration and WSDL definition
 */
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    public final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( WebServiceConfig.class );

    // Skipping other bean declarations...

    @Bean(name = "soapFaultAnnotationExceptionResolver")
    public DetailSoapFaultDefinitionExceptionResolver exceptionResolver( ApplicationContext applicationContext ){
        DetailSoapFaultDefinitionExceptionResolver exceptionResolver = new DetailSoapFaultDefinitionExceptionResolver();

        SoapFaultDefinition soapFaultDefinition = new SoapFaultDefinition();
        soapFaultDefinition.setFaultCode( SoapFaultDefinition.SERVER );
        exceptionResolver.setDefaultFault( soapFaultDefinition );

        return exceptionResolver;
    }

}
```

Comment: @Bean(name = "soapFaultAnnotationExceptionResolver")  this annotation save my day... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I know that this response is outdated but maybe it works for someone else.

MessageDispatcher raise two Resolvers by default: SimpleSoapExceptionResolver and SoapFaultAnnotationExceptionResolver in that order, if you want to get a soap fault with custom code and error message, you must declare the correct order to get SoapFaultAnnotationExceptionResolver first, and then SimpleSoapExceptionResolver.

Step 1. On bean configuration file corresponding:

```
<bean   class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.SoapFaultAnnotationExceptionResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.SimpleSoapExceptionResolver">
    <property name="order" value="2"/>
</bean>
```

Step 2. Declare your Exceptions as follows:

```
@SoapFault(faultCode = FaultCode.CUSTOM,locale="en",faultStringOrReason = "CUSTOM_MESSAGE",customFaultCode="YOUR_NAMESPACE + YOUR_CUSTOM_CODE")

public class DeclaracionNotFoundException extends BusinessException {

public DeclaracionNotFoundException(){
    super();
}

public DeclaracionNotFoundException(String message) {
    super(message);
}
}
```

Step 3.

Raise your Exception in your code normally

throws new DeclaracionNotFoundException(); //With default message from faultStringOrReason
    or
   throws new DeclaracionNotFoundException("Ops!!!"); //With other message

It works for me, and I got the following:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode xmlns:ns0="http://com.example">ns0:4</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en">Ops !!!</faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I defined faultCode = 4 and faultString=Ops !!!

Regards

Comment: What should we use for `YOUR_NAMESPACE + YOUR_CUSTOM_CODE` ? I am getting error `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: faultCode's namespaceUri cannot be empty`