# JAX-WS spring server-side set custom fault message for RuntimeExceptions

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jax-ws, jax-ws-customization

## Problem

By default, JAX-WS builds the following SOAP fault message when an uncaught exception that extends `RuntimeException` occurs on my server:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <S:Fault xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
         <faultcode>S:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>[runtime exception message here]</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ns2:exception class="java.lang.RuntimeException" note="To disable this feature, set com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.disableCaptureStackTrace system property to false" xmlns:ns2="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/">
               <message>[runtime exception message here too]</message>
               <ns2:stackTrace>
                  [stack trace details]
               </ns2:stackTrace>
            </ns2:exception>
         </detail>
      </S:Fault>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Which kind of make sense, except that I'd like to change that behavior in order to send that instead:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <S:Fault xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
         <faultcode>S:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Something wrong happened and it's totally our fault</faultstring>
      </S:Fault>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Note that the message should **NOT** be the RuntimeException's message content, but a custom **static message** for **any** exception that extends `RuntimeException` that may occur server-side.

I can't change the WSDL and I don't want to set a custom exception.

I'm using the spring plugin: `com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet`

How can I do that?

Comment: Right in `exception` tag there is an attribute `note` that says 'To disable this feature, set com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.disableCaptureStackTrace system property to false'. Did you try that? Did you try to find out whether there is a property to disable entire details?

Comment: Yeah, and that's not really what I want.

Comment: Isn't this similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069114/adding-detail-in-a-ws-soapfault-my-custom-exceptionresolver-is-not-used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can approach the problem using SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver
http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html

> The SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver is a more sophisticated
>   implementation. This resolver enables you to take the class name of
>   any exception that might be thrown and map it to a SOAP Fault, like
>   so:

```
<beans>
    <bean id="exceptionResolver"
        class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver">
        <property name="defaultFault" value="SERVER"/>
        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <value>
                org.springframework.oxm.ValidationFailureException=CLIENT,Invalid request
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean> </beans>
```

> The key values and default endpoint use the format
>   faultCode,faultString,locale, where only the fault code is required.
>   If the fault string is not set, it will default to the exception
>   message. If the language is not set, it will default to English. The
>   above configuration will map exceptions of type
>   ValidationFailureException to a client-side SOAP Fault with a fault
>   string "Invalid request", as can be seen in the following response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
       <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
           <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
           <faultstring>Invalid request</faultstring>
       </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

> If any other exception occurs, it will return the default fault: a
>   server-side fault with the exception message as fault string.

You should change the org.springframework.oxm.ValidationFailureException exception to the exceptions that you interested ie java.lang.Exception or java.lang.RuntimeException

You could also create a custom exception class

```
public class CustomGenericAllException extends RuntimeException {


    private String errorCode;
    private String errorMsg;

   //getter and setter for errorCode and errorMsg       

    public CustomGenericAllException(String errorCode, String errorMsg) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.errorMsg = errorMsg;
    }

}
```

in every method you can throw this exception

```
 throw new CustomGenericAllException("S:Server", "Something wrong happened and it's totally our fault");
```

and in the xml configuration you can map this generic exception
`<value>com.testpackage.CustomGenericAllException ...`.

Hope this helps

Comment: I read about SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver in the past, but I have troubles finding the correct version of Spring WS (I'm on JDK6 with Spring 3.1.2 packages)

Comment: Can you use spring ws 2.1.4? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have an endpoint similar to the one below:

```
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.PayloadRoot;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.RequestPayload;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapFaultException;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

@Endpoint
public class HolidayEndpoint {

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://mycompany.com/hr/schemas";

    public HolidayEndpoint() {
    }

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "HolidayRequest")                  
    public void handleHolidayRequest(@RequestPayload Element holidayRequest)               
        throws Exception {
      //your code to handle the request on the server
    }
}
```

Now, let's say handleHolidayRequest() is where you anticipate the RuntimeException to happen, the would have to change the code like so:

```
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.PayloadRoot;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.RequestPayload;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapFaultException;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

@Endpoint
public class HolidayEndpoint {

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://mycompany.com/hr/schemas";

    public HolidayEndpoint() {
    }

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "HolidayRequest")                  
    public void handleHolidayRequest(@RequestPayload Element holidayRequest)               
        throws Exception {
        try
        {
            //your code to handle the request on the server
        }
        catch(RuntimeException e)
        {
            String faultMessage = "Something's wrong on our end. Try again later.";
            throw new SoapFaultException(faultMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Note how I catch the runtime exception and throw an new SoapFaultException? That does the trick and the response is like so:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en">Something's wrong on our end. Try again later.</faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Now, if you are using something like spring-integration with a service activator, it's just the same concept except instead of throw the SoapFaultException, you are just going to build a message with the SoapFaultException as the payload:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "input", outputChannel = "output")
public Message<?> handleHolidayRequest(HolidayRequest holidayRequest) {
   try {
      // your code to handle the request on the server
   } catch (RuntimeException e) {
      String faultMessage = "Something's wrong on our end. Try again later.";
      SoapFaultException soapFaultException = new SoapFaultException(faultMessage);
      return MessageBuilder.withPayload(soapFaultException).build();
   }
}
```

PS: For your understanding, I used the web service tutorial example from here for illustration (and I do have a working example if you are still struggling):
http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/tutorial.html

Good luck!

Comment: Man, I think you're kind of off topic because of this particular sentence : "I can't change the WSDL and I don't want to set a custom exception".
What I want is to change the default exception to soap fault behavior.

Comment: Ok, understood. I am glad that SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver worked out for you.